# How to draw multiple surface plots at the same mesh in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, surf

I use this code to draw a Gaussian normal distribution. I want to plot several distributions at an equal distance from the original one (like the figure).

[image]

```
lambda = 1;               % wavelength

E0 = 1;                   % max value of E-field amplitude

% ==================================================================
% prepare the coordinates mesh
% ----------------------------

zLin = linspace(-201,201,400) * lambda;     % z-coordinate (horizontal)

rLin = linspace(-65,65,100) * lambda;       % radius-coordinate (vertical)

[z,r] = meshgrid(zLin,rLin);                % create mesh


% ===================================================================

wFactor = 4;                 
    
w0 = wFactor * lambda;                  % minimal waist

zR = pi* w0^2 / lambda;                 % Rayleigh length

w = w0 * sqrt( 1 + (z / zR) .^2 );      % Beam radius at any arbitrary distance (equ. 3)

% Irradiance
eta = 377;                              % for free space
I0 = abs(E0)^2/eta;

I = I0 .* (w0 ./ w).^2 .* exp( -2*(r./w).^2 );

surf(z,r,I); shading interp
```

Comment: You can either add the plots together and then do 1 plot, or use `hold on`

Comment: Thank you for your fast response.
I already tried to do so but what I get is the same mesh with the distribution but with a displacement NOT ON THE SAME MESH.
I used this code 
`dist = 50;`
`surf(z1,r1+dist,I1)`

Comment: Right, because you you are changing where to plot the same `I1`, not changing `I1` itself. You need to make `I2` with a offset

Comment: Ok I tried to add some offset to I1 like I2 = I1 + 50, and It worked properly.
Now I try to do the same for I3 but the whole figure is runid.
I2 is added above I1 (in the y axis), how can I add I3 next to I1 in the X-axis